# Reduce number of null values in MODIS surface temperature data

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, modis

I am trying to reduce the number of null (no data) values in output data for an area (Tokyo prefecture) in August 2019 when using MODIS 1km spatial resolution daily surface temperature satellite data (MODIS/006/MOD11A1, LST_Day_1km).

I am new to Google Earth Engine and coding but through a combination of watching tutorials, trial and error and cut and pasting from code structures found online (especially from a question asked on StackExchange by GGamer and answered by Kuik) I have managed to produce the following code;

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7e467c91855832cce3b65c5dfce4dd1e

However my output data (in degrees celsius) for each point on each day in August in the Tokyo area always has a large number of nulls, for example;

```
FeatureCollection (2100 elements, 32 columns)
type: FeatureCollection
columns: Object (32 properties)
features: List (2100 elements)
1: Feature 1 (Point, 31 properties)
type: Feature
id: 1
geometry: Point (139.01, 35.89)
properties: Object (31 properties)
08_01_2019-08-01: null
08_02_2019-08-02: 24.670000000000016
08_03_2019-08-03: null
08_04_2019-08-04: 24.55000000000001
08_05_2019-08-05: 24.250000000000057
08_06_2019-08-06: 26.130000000000052
08_07_2019-08-07: 24.910000000000025
08_08_2019-08-08: null
08_09_2019-08-09: 26.57000000000005
08_10_2019-08-10: null
08_11_2019-08-11: null
08_12_2019-08-12: null
08_13_2019-08-13: null
08_14_2019-08-14: null
08_15_2019-08-15: null
08_16_2019-08-16: null
08_17_2019-08-17: null
08_18_2019-08-18: null
08_19_2019-08-19: null
08_20_2019-08-20: null
08_21_2019-08-21: null
08_22_2019-08-22: null
08_23_2019-08-23: null
08_24_2019-08-24: 18.010000000000048
08_25_2019-08-25: null
08_26_2019-08-26: null
08_27_2019-08-27: null
08_28_2019-08-28: null
08_29_2019-08-29: null
08_30_2019-08-30: null
ID: 1
```

Is there something I can add to/remove from my code to reduce the amount of nulls? Or is this unavoidable? Or perhaps combining with a different dataset is another option to fill the gaps, for example MODIS/006/MYD11A1, LST_Day_1km?

Comment: Japan is a cloudy place, nulls will be unavoidable. You could fill the NULLS by interpolating from known values, but that might not be a solution.

Comment: That is great, thank you very much for your reply!